# Is it possible to open file with com.apple.quarantine on Windows device?

Tags: windows, macos, permissions

I am new to web development, and I have downloaded the source file from AWS. However all the file (e.g css, js) seems to have "com.apple.quarantine" preventing me to view and edit it. I tried google the solution, but seems like most people just want to open on Mac OS. Is there a way to do it on Windows?

Comment: Your computer thinks it's malware. I'd advise against opening it elsewhere unless you're certain it's ok. But, yes, a js file can be opened on just about any computer. The question is: what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried open on notebook and Vistual studio code. When I open the file on notebook, it shows "com.apple.quarantine q/0082;5f334b2b;filezilla;"?

I have also tried "xattr -d com.apple.quarantine my_file_location" on cmd, didn't seems it works on windows.

Comment: Is there a way to disable Windows for doing that?

Comment: I'd be inclined to wonder how the com.apple.quarantine got there in the first place. It is applied to any file downloaded from an insecure source to a Mac. Only the Mac knows what it is & what it's for. It will be removed once the developer's signature is confirmed at file open. Windows will not add the flag nor will it have any clue what to do with it. I'd refer back to your source.

Comment: It almost sounds like the file copied to Windows is the resource fork, not the original file.  I didn't think Macs really used resource forks anymore.  Did you copy from the Mac, or you think a Mac developer uploaded to AWS, and you're downloading to Windows?  My guess is that the Mac developer uploaded the wrong "fork" to AWS.  Check the source directly in AWS (in your browser), if possible.

Comment: @jimtut: it's not the resource fork, but likely the extended attributes which are stored in the same `._` (AppleDouble) file that resource forks are stored in.